# How is tazqiya al qalb related to talqiyya al siir?

Tags: dhikr, self-purification

Salam alaykum.

I understand that the qalb is purified to reflect and that talqiyya al siir is a stage after that but how exactly is the process? 
I read somewhere it's the remembrance of ALLAH attributes.

JZK

Comment: all of these processes are defined by sufi's not by mainstream islamic teachings. So, there will not be any definative answer to this.

Comment: I know they are mostly associated with Sufi tariqas but I want to know what is the mainstream take on this as in the consensus of ullahma? I know there is zuhud in mainstream Islam and how is this related to the above?